# Selenium C# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:'

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Previously working scripts are failing to work on my machine.
Normally use chrome for selenium testing but have tried Firefox and see the exact same error.
I tried writing a basic console app to open the browser but same again whether I ran it from within Visual studio or built the project and executed it outside of VS.
Tried writing a script in java using eclipse and that worked.
Tried using katalon studio and that too could open the browser.
Seems to exclusive to tests executed via visual studio
Using VS 2019 and >Net Core 3.1

Comment: Does the errors says anything more? Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: No further error information the call stack looks normal